# cyclic three variable inequality

Tags: inequality, radicals, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

> Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers and $a+b+c=3$. Prove the inequality
>   $$
>   \sqrt{24a^2b+25}+\sqrt{24b^2c+25}+\sqrt{24c^2a+25}\le 21 
> $$

I have tried to find the solution using classical inequalities, but failed. Any idea?

Comment: But what have you done ?

Comment: tried to apply all kind of classical inequalities,Cauchy,Holder,Jensen,Minkowski,...,but doesnt work

Comment: @calculus it's somewhat difficult to make progress on contest problems in inequalities when there are usually only 2 or 3 ways of tackling it.

Comment: i suppose it is so,but someone might have an idea which leeds to a solution

Comment: try to use the Lagrange Multiplier method

Comment: From symmetry you might expect the a=b=c=1 to be a critical point of the right hand side. By inspection, it gives equality in the inequality. Thus you might check this as well.

Comment: The best way is what @kodlu said, check the corners (3,0,0) and the middle (1,1,1). The trick is then, to *rigorously* prove there are no extremal points between them, or if they are, they are not maxima. You can observe the values of $a^2b$ on triangle $a+b+c=3$, and work from there.

Comment: unfortunetly nobody reads the comments,equality holds at $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,1,0)$ and its cyclic permutations

Comment: I'm just wondering: where do you have the inequality from?

Comment: it is mine,i have a kind of solution but it requires a lot of calculation and it is really uggly.Now i will post helping inequality maby someone has a nice solution for that

Comment: I think, that we have generally $\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{x a^2b+y}≤\max{\left(3\sqrt{x+y},\sqrt{4x+y}+2\sqrt{y}\right)}}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Proof without words** (more like a pictural comment). The following reference gives some clues about the know how to do such a thing:

- [Example of a Problem Made Easier with Skew Coordinates](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837245/example-of-a-problem-made-easier-with-skew-coordinates/)

[image]         [image]

Define the function to be investigated as:
$$
F(a,b,c) = \sqrt{24a^2b+25}+\sqrt{24b^2c+25}+\sqrt{24c^2a+25} - 21
$$
Scanning the inside of the triangle (picture on the left) pixel by pixel (i.e. numerically) reveals that:

```
minimum = -5.97874499595267E+0000 ; maximum = -1.86093567294196E-0005
```

The exact minimum is at the vertices of the triangle: $F(3,0,0)=F(0,3,0)=F(0,0,3)=-6$ , just beyond reach of the numerics.
Contour lines of the function are shown in the picture on the right.
They are at:

```
for g := 1 to 16 do
begin
  level := -sqr(g/8); { level = minus g/8 squared }
```

More black means closer to the maximum. Of course we already know that:
$$
F(1,1,1) =  0 \; ; \; F(2,1,0) =  0 \; ; \; F(0,2,1) =  0 \; ; \; F(1,0,2) =  0
$$
These places are indicated as $\color{blue}{blue}$ spots in the picture on the right. So there is strong evidence (ipse est NO "rigorous proof") that $0$ is *indeed* the maximum. My 2 cents worth ..

EDITs. Picture on the right augmented with $\color{green}{green}$ areas where $|F(a,b,c)| < 0.1$ .
If $F(a,b,c)$ is specified for an edge of the equilateral triangle, then we can do some analytical work, though it remains a modest attempt:
$$
f(x) = F(3-x,x,0) = \sqrt{24(3-x)^2x+25}-11
$$
Derivative zero:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}24\frac{-2(3-x)x+(3-x)^2}{\sqrt{24(3-x)^2x+25}} = 0
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad x\in\{3,1\}
$$
Giving the known minimum $F(0,3,0)$ and the known maximum $F(2,1,0)$ , the only difference being that these are now proven unique, at the triangle's edges.

In order to demonstrate that the problem is "not so easy", let's specify again, for a line through one vertex of the triangle $(3,0,0)$ and the midpoint $(1,1,1)$:
$$
g(x) = F(3-2x,x,x) = \sqrt{24(3-2x)^2x+25}+\sqrt{24x^3+25}+\sqrt{x^2(3-2x)+25}-21
$$
Then we already *know* that a solution of $g'(x)=0$ is given by $F(1,1,1)=0$. But, if this is fed into [MAPLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)) , then all I've got is a seemingly endless loop:

```
> solve(diff(g(x),x)=0,x);
Warning, computation interrupted
```

Comment: A plausability check of this situation via Wolfram Alpha is affirmative. Regrettably, an analytic proof looking for local maxima and maxima at the boundaries seems to be rather cumbersome. In fact, I would really appreciate if someone could provide a technique based upon clever manipulations using inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{24a^2b+25}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}(24a^2b+25)(a+3b+5c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+3b+5c}$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(24a^2b+25)(a+3b+5c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+3b+5c}\leq441$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(648a^2b+25(a+b+c)^3)(a+3b+5c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+3b+5c}\leq441(a+b+c)^3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(20a^6+47a^5b+352a^5c-209a^4b^2+509a^4c^2-275a^3b^3+$$
$$+690a^4bc-556a^3b^2c-143a^3c^2b-435a^2b^2c^2)\geq0.$$
Now, let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$4779(u^2-uv+v^2)a^4+27(263u^3-211u^2v+130uv^2+263v^3)a^3+$$
$$+9(365u^4-58u^3v-453u^2v^2+965uv^3+365v^4)a^2+$$
$$+3(173u^5+169u^4v-739u^3v^2+356u^2v^3+1156uv^4+173v^5)a+$$
$$+(u-2v)^2(20u^4+127u^3v+219u^2v^2+93uv^3+5v^4)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!