# Books similar to "The Cauchy-Schwarz master class"

Tags: inequality, reference-request, book-recommendation

I've been reading the book [The Cauchy-Schwarz master class](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~ehudf/courses/Ineq09/The%20Cauchy-Schwarz%20Master%20Class%20.pdf) and I'm enjoying it very much so far. In particular, I very much like the style of exposition which explains, connects and illustrates great ideas in inequalities well, shows some interesting advanced applications, and provides historical background. Moreover, I wish I'd read (parts of) it back in high school, as there are many gems in it which come up in math Olympiads; it's amazing how the book manages to be relevant for mathematicians in all stages of their development. Overall, I believe reading it will be an enjoyable experience which will give me a more holistic and principled perspective on the art of inequalities.

Are you aware of books that do a similar thing for other areas of math?

Comment: In my opinion, this book is hopelessly outdated now.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: There are many new methods with C-S.

Comment: Is there a good reference?

Comment: I think the best way to learn C-S it's to read a posts of can_hang2007 and quykhtn-qa1 in the inequalities forum : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg "Hopelessly outdated"? "Many new methods with C-S" since 2004? Please name three.  Do you think Polya's "inequalities", Zygmund's "Trigonometric Series" are also hopelessly outdated?

Comment: @uniquesolution For example, see my solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413271  this trick is very useful and helps for the proof of very hard inequalities. We can use this trick with Holder. Also, there is the $uvw$ method:https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791 Good luck!

Comment: I have already contributed my modest opinion regarding the $abc$ circular - completely useless - inequalities which you seem to have an unsatiable lust for, elsewhere. Do you have real-mathematics examples?

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't like your tone. In this tone I'am not ready to talk.