# Find proof for sum of cyclic square root inequality where $a+b+c=3.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

While solving one inequality which posted by @arqady-AOPS. (See [unsolved inequality.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1438452p8166358))
$$\color{black}{\sqrt{24a^2b+25}+\sqrt{24b^2c+25}+\sqrt{24c^2a+25}\le 21,}$$I arrived at a much simpler, but still nontrivial inequality$$\color{black}{\sqrt{144a^2b+25c^2}+\sqrt{144b^2c+25a^2}+\sqrt{144c^2a+25b^2}\le 39.}$$
where $a,b,c$ are non-negative real numbers and $a+b+c=3.$

It apparently holds, but I haven't found a proof so far.

As @arqady wrote the title of his AOPS post, this kind of cyclic sum of square root inequalities seems nice look but not easy at all.

We can easily check that equality holds at $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1); (2,1,0)$ and its cyclic permutations.

That's why$$\color{black}{\sqrt{144a^2b+25c^2}+\sqrt{144b^2c+25a^2}+\sqrt{144c^2a+25b^2}\le \sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{144(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+25(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\le 39}$$ doesn't help here.

I hope you can help me prove it. Any ideas and comments are welcome.

Comment: How do you know that the inequality “apparently holds” if you do not have a proof? – Why is this “simpler” than the other inequality?

Comment: The problem which is "simpler" is not simple at all. Which exactly do you want to ask?

Comment: It was here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413271/cyclic-three-variable-inequality

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you. How about my second inequality? I think the Bacteria helps.

Answer (score 0):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{144a^2b+25c^2}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{144a^2b+25c^2}{58a^2+28b^2+83c^2+338ab}\sum_{cyc}(58a^2+28b^2+83c^2+338ab)}=$$
$$=39\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{144a^2b+25c^2}{58a^2+28b^2+83c^2+338ab}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{432a^2b+25c^2(a+b+c)}{58a^2+28b^2+83c^2+338ab}\leq a+b+c,$$ which is obvious by BW: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%2By%2Bz-%28432x%5E2y%2B25z%5E2%28x%2By%2Bz%29%29%2F%2858x%5E2%2B28y%5E2%2B83z%5E2%2B338xy%29-%28432y%5E2z%2B25x%5E2%28x%2By%2Bz%29%29%2F%2858y%5E2%2B28z%5E2%2B83x%5E2%2B338yz%29-%28432z%5E2x%2B25y%5E2%28x%2By%2Bz%29%29%2F%2858z%5E2%2B28x%5E2%2B83y%5E2%2B338zx%29%2Cx%3Da%2Cy%3Da%2Bu%2Cz%3Da%2Bv