# Roundest ellipse with specified tangents

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Suppose you are given two points $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$ in the plane with associated vectors $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$. You want to find an ellipse passing through $\mathbf p_1$ tangent to $\mathbf v_1$ and through $\mathbf p_2$ tangent to $\mathbf v_2$. [There are infinitely many solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109890/856),

[image]
[image]

but a natural choice is to take the one that is the closest to a circle, i.e. the one with the minimum eccentricity. Is there an elegant way to compute such an ellipse given $(\mathbf p_1, \mathbf v_1)$ and $(\mathbf p_2, \mathbf v_2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891647/856) to [a previous not-quite-duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891085/856), achille hui has given an elegant coordinate-free solution, which I summarize below.

Choose the origin at the intersection of the two desired tangent lines, so that $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$ are interpreted as vectors from the intersection to the two input points. Let $\mathbf q_1,\mathbf q_2$ be the dual basis for $\mathbf p_1,\mathbf p_2$, that is, $\mathbf p_1\cdot \mathbf q_1 = \mathbf p_2\cdot \mathbf q_2 = 1$ and $\mathbf p_1\cdot \mathbf q_2 = \mathbf p_2\cdot \mathbf q_1 = 0$. The equation for the minimum-eccentricity ellipse is
$$(\mathbf{q}_1\cdot \mathbf{x} - 1)^2
+ (\mathbf{q}_2\cdot \mathbf{x} - 1)^2
+ 2\alpha(\mathbf{q}_1\cdot \mathbf{x})(\mathbf{q}_2\cdot \mathbf{x}) = 1,$$
where
$$\alpha = \frac{2\mathbf{p}_1\cdot\mathbf{p}_2}{\|\mathbf{p}_1\|^2 + \|\mathbf{p}_2\|^2}.$$

For the derivation, see [the original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891647/856).

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to do this construction in a purely geometrical way, without coordinates. Let $A$, $B$ be the given tangency points (called $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$ in the question) and $AV$, $BV$ the corresponding tangents (the case when tangents are parallel can be dealt with in a simpler way, see below).

If $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, for a well-known property of the ellipse line $VM$ is a diameter, and we are free to choose on it a point $D$, to construct the ellipse touching the given tangents at $A$, $B$ and passing through $D$. The construction is quite simple, because the line through $D$ parallel to $AB$, meeting line $VA$ at $E$, is another tangent: if $F$ is the midpoint of $AD$ it follows that $EF$ is also a diameter, and the intersection $C$ of $VM$ and $EF$ is thus the center of the ellipse (see diagram). With the center and three points, the ellipse can be easily constructed.

[image]

But of course we must choose point $D$ such that the eccentricity of the ellipse be minimum. To that end, draw line $GC$ parallel to $AB$ and notice that lines $CD$ and $CG$ form a pair of conjugate diameters. Apollonius' equations connect semidiameters $CD$ and $CG$ with standard semiaxes $a$ and $b$ of the ellipse:
$$
CD^2+CG^2=a^2+b^2,\quad CD\cdot CG\sin\theta = ab,
$$
where $\theta=\angle VMA$. From there it is not difficult to find an expression for the eccentricity $\epsilon$ as a function of $t=CD/CG$:
$$
\epsilon^2={2\over1+1/\xi},
\quad\hbox{where}\quad
\xi=\sqrt{1-\left({2t\over1+t^2}\right)^2\sin^2\theta}.
$$
It follows that

> the minimum value of the eccentricity, 
>   $\epsilon=\sqrt{2\over1+1/|\cos\theta|}$, is obtained when
>   $CD=CG$.

To exploit that condition, notice that $(AM/CG)^2+(CM/CD)^2=1$ and if $CD=CG$ this is equivalent to
$$
AM^2+CM^2=CD^2.
$$
Playing around with similar triangles one also finds $CD/MC=1+VM/MD$: combining those equalities we finally get
$$
MD={AM^2+AM\sqrt{AM^2+VM^2}\over VM}.
$$
From that, one can construct point $D$ and then find center $C$ as explained above.

If tangent lines are parallel, $A$ and $B$ are the endpoints of a diameter and center $C$ is their midpoint. Just construct then the conjugate diameter through $C$ parallel to the tangents and take on it point $D$ such that $CD=AC$.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment I can offer an analytical solution, which is quite cumbersome but manageable. I hope someone will be able to give a simpler solution.

To reduce the number of parameters, we can set up a coordinate system such that $\mathbf{p}_1=(\alpha,0)$, $\mathbf{p}_2=(0,\beta)$, $\mathbf{v}_1=(0,1)$, and define then $m=v_{2y}/v_{2x}$.

Let's start with the generic equation for a conic section, where we can set to $1$ the coefficient of $x^2$ because we are dealing with an ellipse:
$$
x^2+By^2+Cxy+Dx+Ey+F=0.
$$

We have four conditions: the conic passes through $\mathbf{p}_1$, $\mathbf{p}_2$ and is there tangent to $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$. These conditions translate into four equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\cases{
\alpha^2+\alpha D+F=0\\
\beta^2B+\beta E+F=0\\
2m\beta B+\beta C+D+mE=0\\
\alpha C+E=0
}
\end{align}
$$
From there, one can find expressions for $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ as a function of $F$. Plugging these into the [formulas for the semiaxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Canonical_form) $a$ and $b$ we can then compute the eccentricity $\epsilon=\sqrt{1-b^2/a^2}$. The smaller the eccentricity, the rounder the ellipse, so we must find the minimum of $\epsilon$ as a function of $F$.

I computed $d\epsilon/dF$ with Mathematica and found that it vanishes for
$$
F=-\frac{\alpha ^2 \beta  \left(\alpha ^2 \beta +\beta ^3-2 \alpha ^2 \beta  m^2+2 \alpha ^3
   m\right)}{\beta ^2 \left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right)+2 m^2 \left(\alpha ^4+2 \alpha ^2 \beta
   ^2\right)+2 \alpha  \beta  m \left(\alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2\right)}.
$$

Once $F$ is known, one can compute the other coefficients and find the equation of the "roundest" ellipse:
$$
\begin{align}
\cases{
B=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha ^2 \left(\beta ^2+\alpha ^2 \left(2 m^2+1\right)+2 \alpha  \beta  m\right)}{\displaystyle\beta ^2\left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right)+2 m^2 \left(\alpha ^4+2 \alpha ^2 \beta ^2\right)+2 \alpha 
   \beta  m \left(\alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2\right)}\\
\\
C=\frac{\displaystyle2 \alpha ^2 m \left(-\alpha ^2+\beta ^2+2 \alpha  \beta  m\right)}{\displaystyle\beta ^2 \left(\alpha
   ^2+\beta ^2\right)+2 m^2 \left(\alpha ^4+2 \alpha ^2 \beta ^2\right)+2 \alpha  \beta  m
   \left(\alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2\right)}\\
\\
D=-\frac{\displaystyle2 \alpha ^2 m \left(2 \beta ^3+m \left(\alpha ^3+3 \alpha  \beta ^2\right)\right)}{\displaystyle\beta ^2
   \left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right)+2 m^2 \left(\alpha ^4+2 \alpha ^2 \beta ^2\right)+2 \alpha 
   \beta  m \left(\alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2\right)}\\
\\
E=-\frac{\displaystyle2 \alpha ^3 m \left(-\alpha ^2+\beta ^2+2 \alpha  \beta  m\right)}{\displaystyle\beta ^2 \left(\alpha
   ^2+\beta ^2\right)+2 m^2 \left(\alpha ^4+2 \alpha ^2 \beta ^2\right)+2 \alpha  \beta  m
   \left(\alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2\right)}
}
\end{align}
$$

A [check with GeoGebra](https://ggbm.at/hjTZjKvj) confirms that this is indeed the value of $F$ giving a minimum eccentricity.

EDIT.

Following the suggestion by Rahul, we can get a much simpler result. Choose a coordinate system such that 
$\mathbf{p}_1=(\alpha,0)$, $\mathbf{p}_2=(-\alpha,0)$, 
and define $m=v_{1y}/v_{1x}$, $n=v_{2y}/v_{2x}$.

With those choices, the equation of the ellipse can be written as:
$$
x^2+By^2-{m+n\over mn}xy+\alpha{m-n\over mn}y-\alpha^2=0.
$$
The eccentricity $\epsilon$ is then a function of $B$, and 
$d\epsilon/dB=0$ for
$$
B=1+\frac{(m+n)^2}{2 m^2 n^2}.
$$
In summary, the equation of the roundest ellipse turns out to be:
$$
x^2+\left(1+\frac{(m+n)^2}{2 m^2 n^2}\right)y^2-{m+n\over mn}xy+\alpha{m-n\over mn}y-\alpha^2=0.
$$

---

**Added by Rahul:**

Things become even simpler if we use the slope of the *normals*, $\mu=-1/m$ and $\nu=-1/n$:
$$
x^2+\left(1+\tfrac12(\mu+\nu)^2\right)y^2+(\mu+\nu)xy+\alpha(\mu-\nu)y-\alpha^2=0.
$$

Comment: Wow! Sorry, I'll wait for an answer that gives more geometric insight. +1 though.

Comment: Inspired by your answer I took a little stab at it myself. It seems that choosing a coordinate system such that $\mathbf p_1=(-\alpha,0)$ and $\mathbf p_2=(\alpha,0)$ makes things cleaner. In particular, the quadratic reduces to $x^2+By^2+Cxy+Ey-\alpha^2=0$, after which the tangent vectors should determine $C$ and $E$ and leave $B$ as the sole free parameter, though I haven't worked it out all the way. Could you plug it into your Mathematica code and see what comes out?

Comment: You are absolutely right: it is much simpler with the choice you suggest. I'll edit my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is a nice and clean solution. I made a small addition to the end -- I hope you don't mind, feel free to remove it if you do.

Comment: I also found a geometrical construction, see my second answer.

Comment: I saw it, liked it, and gave it a +1; I think it's a shame that it didn't get any other upvotes. It's a lovely solution, and very impressive that it can be achieved using purely Euclidean geometry. But for me achille hui's solution is still the most elegant so I'm keeping it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Least eccentric ellipses for geometric Hermite interpolation
John C. Femiani, Chia-Yuan Chuang, Anshuman Razdan
Computer Aided Geometric Design 29 (2012) 141–149

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement a solution to this problem and wound up frustrated with the existing StackExchange answers. I can't say whether a given answer is right or wrong; only that I tried reducing a few of the more straightforward answers to practice and couldn't get them working.

I had more luck with the combination of (the already mentioned) "Least eccentric ellipses for geometric Hermite interpolation" by Femiani, Chuang, and Razdan (Computer Aided Geometric Design 29, 2012 pp. 141-9) and "Characteristics of conic segments in Bezier form" by Javier Sánchez-Reyes (Proceedings of the IMProVe 2011, pp. 231-4).

Below is an Octave script making use of the calculations of these papers. I calculate *x1* and *y1* from the first paper by different means (and they may sometimes have different signs), but the equivalence should be easy to verify. The complex-number calculations from the second paper can be easily implemented in C using `complex.h`. I include an alternate version of `projPointOnLine()` for reference. The lines below the `ang` calculation present a figure with the calculated ellipse.

````
pkg load symbolic geometry

function rp = ppol(l1, l2, p)
  if (l2(1) == l1(1))
    rp(1) = l2(1);
    rp(2) = p(2);
  else
    m = (l2(2) - l1(2)) / (l2(1) - l1(1));
    b = l1(2) - m * l1(1);
    rp(1) = (m * p(2) + p(1) - m * b) / (m * m + 1);
    rp(2) = (m * m * p(2) + m * p(1) + b) / (m * m + 1);
  endif
endfunction

# Points and slopes
p0 = [ -4, 3 ];
h0 = [ -.8, .3 ];
p2 = [ 2, -1 ];
h2 = [ 2.2, -3 ];

# "Least eccentric ellipses for geometric Hermite interpolation"
# Femiani, Chuang, and Razdan
# Computer Aided Geometric Design 29, 2012 pp. 141-9
# (x1 and y1 calculated by different means)
l0 = createLine([ p0, h0 ]);
l2 = createLine([ p2, h2 ]);
p1 = intersectLines(l0, l2)

l3 = createLine(p0, p2);
p1p = projPointOnLine(p1, l3);
# p1p = ppol(p0, p2, p1);
ph = (p0 + p2) / 2;
vn = vectorNorm(p2-p0);
x1 = 2 * vectorNorm(p1p-ph) / vn
y1 = 2 * vectorNorm(p1p-p1) / vn
w = 1 / sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2 + 1)

# "Characteristics of conic segments in Bezier form"
# Javier Sanchez-Reyes
# Proceedings of the IMProVe 2011, pp. 231-4
# (all calculations between b0 and F2 are complex)
b0 = p0(1) + p0(2) * i;
b1 = p1(1) + p1(2) * i;
b2 = p2(1) + p2(2) * i;

alpha = 1/(1-w**2)
m = (b0 + b2)/2;
C = (1-alpha) * b1 + alpha * m
d = (1-alpha) * b1**2 + alpha * b0 * b2;
c = sqrt(C**2 - d);
F1 = C + c
F2 = C - c
a = (abs(F1 - b0) + abs(F2 - b0))/2
b = sqrt(a**2 - abs(c)**2) # Note: This is reversed in paper
ang = rad2deg(arg(c))

figure;
hold on;
axis equal;
drawEllipse(real(C), imag(C), a, b, ang, 'color', 'magenta');
drawLine(l0, 'color', 'cyan');
drawLine(l2, 'color', 'cyan');
drawLine(l3, 'color', 'blue');
#drawPoint(ph, 'color', 'blue');
drawPoint(p0, 'color', 'black');
drawPoint(p1, 'color', 'blue');
drawPoint(p2, 'color', 'black');
waitforbuttonpress();

```
````